# Typescript: Get correct value type from object by key generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

in the example I want to write an simple query builder where all types of an entity are correctly casted. For example when im filtering with equalsTo for name I only want to allow strings as values, same for age there should only be numbers allow. Now value can be any value of Dogs and thats not what I want. Can somebody help me is this possible?

```
class Dogs {
    name!: string;
    age!: number;
    alive!: boolean;
}
interface QueryBuilder<O extends object, F extends keyof O = keyof O> {
    equalsTo: (fieldName: F, value: O[F]) => boolean;
}
const queryBuilder = <O extends object>(): QueryBuilder<O> => ({
    equalsTo: (fieldName, value) => true 
})
const qb = queryBuilder<Dogs>();
qb.equalsTo("name", 1); // Should throw an error that only string is allowed as value
qb.equalsTo("age", "Rex"); // Should throw an error that only number is allowed as value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface definition:

```
interface QueryBuilder<O extends object, F extends keyof O = keyof O> {
    equalsTo: (fieldName: F, value: O[F]) => boolean;
}
```

is allowing the second parameter of `equalsTo` to be `string | number | boolean` because TypeScript can't narrow the type any further at the *class* level.

**However** - if you type-annotate *the function itself*:

```
interface QueryBuilder<O extends object> {
    equalsTo: <F extends keyof O = keyof O>(fieldName: F, value: O[F]) => boolean;
}
```

... you get the behaviour you're looking for:

```
qb.equalsTo("name", 1); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)

qb.equalsTo("age", "Rex"); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345)
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzGBvAsAKGt6A7MAtgKYCEAXNBAC4BOAlrogNyY7RiKkW4CuBARkRossOMCDoA3LtH7x4IImFwiAvpkwMqQgGZhgRaAEUeQgJ4AhHnRAATIQB4A8tCIAPbblsx4-AFZEwFQAfNDoothEAI484hAAKvAUDgBirh5EXjAA1kRm8DrQLgC80Ln5hU7BABQ6dER2AHKERBQpADTQkuKmFE4A2ikAugCU0MWhcgpKKpjqGJjA8LjU0DHmVjb2NOPQzume3tC+AUE1IxQmG9Z2jlXjodXhbNGxIAlJ0LX1TS2d3SBTGMJtBaKZoHMRhoMEsVlQ1vxdusaJYbtsHAhkOcRFF+AA6V5xRLVABE+GIJM6AEYRkxoAB6enQADKAAt4Dw7KDWTR4AB3di4Vw0Xk7KissDw5YgMyUWgMRDQOgwcQgflEWzsGAA0yYXEEmJE+CkjhESnQEkAJXcJNpDKZbI5XPFvIFymFou5kuOuBleD4gh2yvYIDVfI1Wq6PSImCAA)

Comment: OMG thank you now I get it why it was not working